# Deploying on Meteorjs cloud Vs personal Meteor server

Tags: meteor

I'm developing a meteorjs application and wondering what is better , actually deploying in meteor js cloud is elegant , free , and work perfectly,  but is this will still free , is their any limit  or compensation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very obscure by nature and will receive mostly opinionated answers. I have a feeling it will be closed before too long but for archival sake and to answer your question. Meteor's current free deployment has no guarantee of uptime and shuts down the app when not in use until another user attempts to access your app. For demo's and prototyping this should be fine.

However I would highly suggest that if you need something reliable and for use in a production environment stay far away from the current Meteor service for deployment. You are limited to a database size and how much access you have to things such as the file server. There are many great services out there that allow you to deploy just as easily.

Check out [modulus.io](http://modulus.io) for super simple deploys. If you are on more of a budget you can choose a service such as Digital Ocean or any other VPS service that allows you to install Ubuntu and use something such as [MUP](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) which is a great package made by Arunoda for deploying to Ubuntu based systems.